# Unable to load a react module as node module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browserify, node-modules, es6-modules

I have a react component in the path
`src/components/test`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';

class TestComp extends React.Component {}
export default TestComp;
```

I am exposing the component in index.js from path
`src/index.js`

```
import TestComp from './components/test';
export {
  TestComp
};
```

I have added `main` in package.json as `"main": "src/index.js"`

I have published a npm package `test-comp` of above application and using same in another application.
`main.js`

```
import {TestComp} from 'test-comp';
```

I am using grunt-browserify in this application with following options set.

```
options: {
        "transform": [
          [
            "babelify",
            {
              "presets": [
                "es2015",
                "react",
                "stage-0"
              ]
            }
          ]
        ],
        browserifyOptions: {
          debug: true,
          extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
          entries: ['main.js']
        }
      }
```

When I run `grunt browserify` getting following error.

```
>> import TestComp from './components/test';
>> ^
>> ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'
Warning: Error running grunt-browserify. Use --force to continue.
```

It probably not understanding the path mentioned in node module or rejecting to understand the same which linting. I even have tried adding following in .eslintrc but no luck

```
{
  "extends": "eslint:recommended",
  "parserOptions": {
      "ecmaVersion": 6,
      "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "env": {
      "browser": true,
      "es6": true
  },
  "ecmaFeatures": {
      "modules": true
  }
}
```

I tried most of SO answers related to this error. But still stuck in same place.

**EDIT**
I am able to browserify first module directly with almost similar configuration. Getting this error when first module is loaded as node dependancy in other application as explained above.

Comment: Could you create a basic repo for us where we could replicate the issue?

Comment: i will try...any suggestions which I missed here?

Comment: Unfortunately, it is unclear from the info provided - a reproducible, minimal example would really help us solve the issue at hand!

Comment: @thecodejack If you use browserify in the package A, and you use browserify for building the package B which depends on A, it will not work. You have to use something like debowerify on the package A.

Comment: oh..ok..wasn't aware of that. Looks like that might be reason. Any specific reason for that? coz I am not browserifying package A from package B. I am just importing some modules of Package A in Package B using browserify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you wrote the module `test-comp` in ES6, using `import` and `export`, and the `main` entry of the `package.json` in `test-comp` refers to `src/index.js`.

The answer is that browserify transforms don't apply to every module you require. They only apply to the immediate project: not the project's dependencies.

If you want to require a module that uses ES6 syntax in browserify, you'll either need to

1. [Add a prepublish script to `test-comp` that transpiles it to ES5, and change the `main` entry of `test-comp` to refer to that ES5 version, not the ES6 version](https://booker.codes/how-to-build-and-publish-es6-npm-modules-today-with-babel/)
2. Add `babelify` as a dependency of `test-comp` and add `babelify` as a browserify transform in the [package's 'browserify' entry](https://github.com/babel/babelify#why-arent-files-in-node_modules-being-transformed), as documented in babelify.

Comment: Interesting. Thought browserify will take care. But I actually reconfigured it using webpack and there was no problem in handling this issue. Most probably handled through babel-loader.